# Check if CosmosDB item exists without try/catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the [Node.js CosmosDB library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js) and I want to check if an item exists.

I have seen some examples which recommend the following:

```
const i = container.item(id);

try {
    const { item } = await i.read();
    // item exists
} catch(e) {
    // item does not exist
}
```

But I don't want to use exceptions for flow control. I also want to avoid using `container.items.query` - I want to use `container.item` if possible.

Can I do this?

---

The reason I would like to know how to do this, is I need to call `Item.replace` to update an item, so I would like to do this:

```
const i = container.item(id);

if (i.exists() === false) {
    return;
}

i.replace(replacement);
```

However, if I have to use `container.items.query`, I will have to do this:

```
const result = container.items.query(myQuery);

if (result.current() === undefined) {
    return;
}

container.item(id).replace(replacement);
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the `replace` in the try clause? The SDK is handling bad cases are exceptions so unless you write a wrapper around it it will throw.

Comment: @NickChapsas I want to avoid using exceptions for flow control as [this is an anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225)

Answer (score 1):

Right now, 404 means we throw.

We're thinking about making not throw. I just created an item on GitHub to track that. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/issues/203

Depending on the size of your document, query can actually be cheaper, because you can query for just the id or _etag instead of the full document. For small documents, read will be cheaper, though.

As a workaround, does upsert work for you?

-- EDIT 1 --

Another, kinda hacky option is to handle the error yourself since it's all promises.

```
const handle404 = (err) => {
    if(err.code && err.code === 404) {
        return { body: undefined, headers: err.headers };
    } else {
        throw err;
    }
} 

const { body: item } = await container.item(id).read().catch(handle404);
```

Comment: Same for Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos nuget. If you want to keep the rule that not finding an item when reading it is a cosmo exception consider adding ExistsAsync<T>.